# More efficient method to search a list of strings for certain strings?

Tags: c#, list, mapping

I have a list of strings. Neither the number of nor the order of these strings is guaranteed. The only thing that is certain is that this list WILL at least contain my 3 strings of interest and inside those strings we'll say "string1", "string2", and "string3" will be contained within them respectively (i.e. these strings can contain more information but those keywords will definitely be in there). I then want to use these results in a function.

My current implementation to solve this is as such:

```
foreach(var item in myList)
{
    if (item.Contains("string1"))
    {
        myFunction1(item);
    }
    else if (item.Contains("string2"))
    {
        myFunction2(item);
    }
    else if (item.Contains("string3"))
    {
        myFunction3(item);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to check string lists and apply functions to those items that match some criteria?

Comment: If it was the whole string you are matching, you might be able to speed it up by making a hash value for each string. That is what Databases and some collections do. You could also end the loop after the 3 expected matches, wich would avoid pointless itteartions. And of course there is always the option to trade off memory for speed (having it written down wich search strings wich input string mathces to in a the source database).

Comment: If your code works but you're looking to improve it then you should maybe post it at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: One final note, is to consider Normalization once you go outside of the English language. There are ambigious ways to write many Unicode Characters and Normalize allows you to deal with them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I don't see how you want to improve this code (apart from more readable method names).

Comment: @TimSchmelter method names aren't real. Just for example's sake

Comment: @Christopher exiting after the 3 matches is a great idea. I've added it now, thanks man.

Comment: @CapnJack: If you want to get around the "if tree" part of the accepted answer, consider switch case with pattern matching (a newer feature of C# 7 I think). Note that nothing here is really a speed improvement. There is only so fast you can compare strings agaisnt another and contaitns is already at the top end. One relevant improvement would be to modify the check to `if(!string1Matched && item.Contains("string1"))` You could use that bool as part of the cancel check too.

Comment: @Christopher Definitely not a large enough list to warrant that but it's a pretty good idea if I did have that trouble. It's because the bool check comes first before the string check so it goes first right? Thus making it a faster check if the string is indeed already matched?

Comment: @CapnJack Yes, && has the short circuit behavior. If the first one fails, Nr. 2 is never even checked. And bool checks are the quickest checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `Regex` for the fixed list of strings, and check which group is present, like this:

```
// Note the matching groups around each string
var regex = new Regex("(string1)|(string2)|(string3)");
foreach(var item in myList) {
    var match = regex.Match(item);
    if (!match.Success) {
        continue;
    }
    if (match.Groups[1].Success) {
        myFunction1(item);
    }
    else if (match.Groups[2].Success)
    {
        myFunction2(item);
    }
    else if (match.Groups[3].Success)
    {
        myFunction3(item);
    }
}
```

This way all three matches would be done with a single pass through the target string.

Comment: This is pretty clever, still have that ugly "if-tree" but I doubt we can avoid that since I have 3 different functions. Great idea.

Comment: Is this really more efficient?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It depends on the length of the string and the actual value of three (yes, "three", as in a number :-) I mean, if OP's actual code uses, say, 40 values or so, and each `item` is very long, then regex-based NFA could give you an edge. For shorter strings and the true value of three there shouldn't be a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce some of the duplicated code in the `if` statements by creating a `Dictionary` that maps the strings to their respective functions.  (This snippet assumes that `myList` contains `string` values, but can easily be adapted to a list of any type.)

```
Dictionary<string, Action<string>> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>
{
    ["string1"] = myFunction1,
    ["string2"] = myFunction2,
    ["string3"] = myFunction3
};

foreach (var item in myList)
{
    foreach (var action in actions)
    {
        if (item.Contains(action.Key))
        {
            action.Value(item);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

For a list of only three items, this might not be much of an improvement, but if you have a large list of strings/functions to search for it can make your code much shorter.  It also means that adding a new string/function pair is a one-line change.  The biggest downside is that the `foreach` loop is a bit more difficult to read.

Comment: The dictionary is clever too but I like the regex approach a little more. Thanks for the answer though!